# Does Postgres Store the POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD When the Data Directory is Created

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Experimenting with Postgres and Pgadmin4 with Docker Compose. Initially I use this as my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    links:
      - "db:psql-server"
```

I ran:

```
chown -R 5050:5050 data
```

So that pgadmin4 could save it's configuration and it worked beautifully. Then I tried to bring it down and update the POSTGRES_PASSWORD to test.

```
docker-compose down
```

UPDATED docker-compose.yml file to:

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: root
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
```

And then brought it back up:

```
docker-compose up
```

To my surprise when connecting to Postgres from Pgadmin4 test does not work as the password, but root does. So my question is when Postgres creates the data directory does it store the credentials somewhere in there? Is there a way to update the password and user once it has been initially created?

Comment: Postgress stores all users and passwords in a database. This database is also persisted in the `data` directory. Thus, if data is already present when the container starts, the password for the initial user is not "overridden".

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you for the ninja quick response friend. I see what you're saying. I was able to connect to the container login and update the password there. Is there a way to do this in the docker-compose.yml file itself?

Comment: No, you need to use the psql `\password` command or something similar, the same as if the database weren't in a container.  PostgreSQL stores it in an encrypted form inside very opaque binary storage and Docker simply doesn't know about it.